# How to resolve Routing Error while setting a ruby application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

while accessing my page on my local http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/index I am getting the Routing Error, No route matches [GET] "/posts/index". I'm a newbie for ruby on rails. I posting the routing page code I'm using. Attaching screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OuF2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `posts_path` or `/posts` is the route to the index page. `posts/index` will look for a post with slug `index` which is not what you want probably.